# Getting PS3 controller input in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input, playstation3

I want my PS3 controller to control my unity game, and so far it isn't going well. I have it plugged into my computer via the USB cable it came with. My computer *did not install any drivers when I plugged it in,* but it did make a sound and Unity seems to have detected it, printing `Joystick Connected (controller name here)`

Unfortunately, beyond that the controller does absolutely nothing. I have gone to the input menu and have adjusted input according to this map: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/ps3-button-map.89288/
[image]

but still get nothing. Not a single button does anything.

I should also mention if this helps, this is how I'm getting input:

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    float movehorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float movevertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    Vector3 movement = new Vector3(movehorizontal, 0, movevertical);
    rb.AddForce(movement * speed);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a special driver in order to get your PS3 controller to work on PC. I highly recommend [ScpToolkit](https://github.com/nefarius/ScpToolkit). It's the best one out there.